# Map entry event listeners are not invoked on clients of WAN replication target cluster

Tags: replication, wan, java-client

This https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/5058 fixes similar issue but on target cluster itself. Clients of such cluster receive `REMOVED` events only. It's fairly easy to reproduce by adding client to `clusterB` in `WanReplicationTest.willFireNewOnMergeEventAtReceivingCluster`.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Not a question, more like a report / request.. Is this not the right place?